# How do you run a T4Toolbox Generator or CSharpTemplate?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, t4, t4-toolbox

I downloaded and installed the [T4Toolbox](http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/) to work with T4 templates more easily... however, I can't even figure out how to run the `Generator` or `CSharpTemplate`.

Here is an example file I created:

**Template1.tt:**

```
<#+
    public class Template1 : CSharpTemplate
    {
        public override string TransformText()
        {
            base.TransformText();
#>

Hello world

<#+
            return this.GenerationEnvironment.ToString();
        }
    }
#>
```

---

I have compiled my application and saved the file, yet no output file(s) are created. :/

Answer (score 1):

You need to have another Template file which will call this template class "Template1 " to render & generate text.

Lets name that file as BuildTemplate.tt and that should contain below code

```
  <#@ template language="C#" debug="True" #>
  <#@ include file="T4Toolbox.tt" #>
  <#@ include file="Template1.tt" #>

 <#
 Template1 ta = new Template1 ();
 ta.Render();
 #>
```

Now just right click on file "BuildTemplate.tt" and select "Run Custom Tool". A .cs file will be generated.

If you want to configure other properties i.e. generate at some specified project, Set CopyToOutputDirectory true/false then you can configure them as below

```
    ta.Output.File = string.Format("Entity\\Entity.cs");
    ta.Output.PreserveExistingFile = true;
    ta.Output.Project = @"..\<Project Folder Path>\<Project File Name>.csproj";
```

You can find more info on configuring properties at 
http://www.olegsych.com/2010/03/t4-tutorial-integrating-generated-files-in-visual-studio-projects/

Answer (score 0):

CSharpTemplate and Generator are classes in the T4Toolbox library. In order to include it to your template, add this line at the top of your .tt file:

```
<#@ include file="T4Toolbox.tt" #>
```